# $(...).pagination is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm getting that error when it reaches this line. I've confirmed that the file jquery.simplePagination.js is present before it gets executed. I also don't see the function "pagination" listed under $.fn.(...).
   After the page loads(and the call fails) the pagination function IS present in that list, but not during the script execution.
   I'm at a loss. jquery is present, the file is present. So why aren't the functions available?
   For what it's worth this works in an isolated environment but not when I deploy it to my Sharepoint website.

```
        $("#quickTables").pagination({
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber){
            $.each( pageArr, function(key, value) {
                var pageDiv = "paginationPageNumber" + pageNumber;
                if (value == pageDiv )
                    $("#" + pageDiv).show();
                else
                    $("#" + pageDiv).hide();
            });
        }
```

Comment: is  jquery.simplePagination.js loaded before this block of code is executed?

Comment: Are you deploying the dependencies with it!

Comment: As @sn3ll said you should add the scripts from the plugin before using it

Comment: OP says in the question "I've confirmed that the file jquery.simplePagination.js is present before it gets executed."

Comment: To reiterate what tymeJV said, yes the file is loaded before the block is executed. All the dependent files are loaded with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps.

1) Check if the pagination jquery is loaded.

If this pagination jquery is loaded then

2) check if there is only one jquery is loaded on the page.